# How does one omit the data types line when printing a tibble?

Tags: r, tibble

In R, is there a way to omit the data types line when printing a `tibble`? I would like to declutter calls to `tibble` objects but can't find an option to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is info on costuming the output in the `pillar` package: `vignette("extending", package="pillar")` .

it looks like you can customize the `tbl_format_body`. We can extend this generic method to respond to a class where you don't want the type to appear. For example

```
tbl_format_body.notype <- function (x, setup, ...) {
  force(setup)
  setup$body[-2]
}
notype <- function(x) {
  class(x) <- c("notype", class(x))
  x
}
notype(tibble(a=1:3, b=letters[1:3]))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#       a b    
# 1     1 a    
# 2     2 b    
# 3     3 c
```

Here I just dropped the second row which I assume usually has the types. You can read all about the stuff you can do on that guide though.